# Unable to access content from aws load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I have created a aws elastic load balancer and associated my existing instance with it. The instance is passing the health test. I accessed my instance directly using the `ip:port` and I am able to view the content. I have linked the same port in the aws configurations. When I try the DNS name in my browser, I do not get any response. What do you think is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

- Is your ELB publicly accessible? (You can see this on the ELB settings page.)
- Does your ELB has the right security group?
- Can you telnet into the ELB on the given port (80?)
- Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?
- Are you using HTTP health check?

update:

- I assume your health check is on port 80, so do you have a listener for that ELB on port 80 to port 80?
- Are you doing HTTP port forwarding ( not TCP)?

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes, Http and Yes